# Do buses run on May 1st in Bavaria?

Tags: public-transport, airports, germany, munich, bavaria

I am interested in landing in München (Munich) on 1st of May, and then taking the bus to Ingolstadt. Does the bus operate on 1 May (since I am only interested in Airport-ZOB Ingolstadt)? This is a public holiday ([Maypole Day](https://www.bavaria.by/experiences/city-country-culture/traditions-customs/1st-may-is-maypole-day-in-bavaria/)) in Bavaria.

I guess it will be sparser, but that's OK. I don't want to book a flight and then find out that there is no bus! I pretended booking a ticket for the bus, but the system says its far too early, so doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I found this [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187309-i118-k5355848-May_1_2012-Munich_Upper_Bavaria_Bavaria.html) question which states that the train will be running, but I am interested in the bus! But that's a positive omen...

Comment: @lightness-races-in-orbit: More importantly it’s a federal public holiday: [International Worker’s Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Workers'_Day#Germany).

Comment: Small anecdote: Last year we blocked a city bus while setting up our Maypole. This year we timed the carrying of the pole specifically so that the bus could pass prior to us using up all space on the street. So, yes, buses do run on May 1st in Bavaria ;-)

Comment: Also note, that many bus schedules change in early December in Germany in a concerted action with the Deutsche Bahn and other public transport providers. So I recommend to retrieve the schedule, that skifans posted, again next year.

Comment: @Boldewyn talk about a caring citizen, nice! Boldewyn, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will try to answer the actual question, instead of writing so much about the irrelevant connection to Ingolstadt Village. As already pointed out in the comments, Ingolstadt Village is an outlet retail park and is therefore only served by a connecting shuttle service when the shops are open (not on Sundays and public holidays). That has however nothing to do with the question asked.

Most public transport services in Germany have a limited time table on Saturdays (abbr. Sa) and Sundays (abbr. So). Public holidays are almost without exception serviced according to the Sunday time table.

The bus from Munich Airport to Ingolstadt runs however according to the same time table every day, also on public holidays. There are hourly services in both directions with only a short break in the night.

Comment: Tor, thank you for the crystal clear answer. I confirmed it officially too, check my [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/124841/41906).

Answer (score 4):

Edit:
As has been pointed out in the comment Ingolstadt Village is not the main stop for Ingolstadt but instead a shopping center - being an English speaker I had assumed incorrectly but should have checked. As far as I am aware nothing written below is incorrect, but some parts are not relevant.

You haven't listed the bus number in your question but as far as I can tell you are asking about the X109 (https://www.invg.de/maps_airport).

The timetable (https://www.invg.de/timetable_airport_express) contains the following notes for the stop Ingolstadt Village which Google translate translates to:

Towards airport:
"For Ingolstadt Village applies: only Monday to Saturday, not on public holidays. Registration at least one hour before the desired departure sign up for information in the Village. The transport takes place via taxi or Minibus to the stop Kurt-Huber-Straße and from there continue with Airport Express to Munich Airport."

Leaving airport:
"For Ingolstadt Village applies: only Monday to Saturday, not on public holidays. Passengers have to change at Kurt-Huber-Straße and From there you can take a taxi or minibus to Ingolstadt Village."

This to me implies that the rest of the bus route runs as normal on public holidays, but the connection to Ingolstadt Village does not run. So what you need to do may depend on how near another stop you are. Alternatively you could try and sort your own taxi or look at other bus services.

I want to stress that this answer is based entirely on what I could fine online, and anyone with any local knowledge or who knows otherwise should please feel free to write another correct answer.

Comment: This is the right answer, but the information about Ingolstadt Village is maybe a bit of a red-herring. Ingolstadt Village appears to be a retail park on the outskirts of town. OP's destination is much more likely to be one of the stops in central Ingolstadt, *am Nordbahnhof* (Ingolstadt North train station) or *ZOB* (long-distance bus station). As you say, services to/from these stops will be running as usual.

Comment: @ChrisH, yes I am going to ZOB, or Nordbahnhof, doesn't matter which one. I am trying to figure out which bus number it is, probably X109. So the question about going from Munich Airport to ZOB Ingolstadt by bus, on May 1, has a positive answer or no? I think you could update your answer skifans, since I am not interested in the village at all, sorry for that.

Comment: @gsamaras yes, you can make the trip by bus on May 1. It should be running to its usual schedule (as linked in the answer, one bus per hour through most of the day).

Comment: Thank you @ChrisH. I think that the answer needs to be updated, since it's not clear . . .

Comment: Ingolstadt is not a village...

Comment: @gerrit "Ingolstadt Village" is (as Chris H already mentioned) a retail park, and buses don't go there on sundays and holidays, as there's nothing to do there when the shops are closed. This neither implies that Ingolstadt is a village nor does it have an impact on buses going from the centre of Ingolstadt to MUC on sundays.

Comment: @gsamaras If the answer is not clear you should not instantly mark it as accepted. You could even wait 24 hours to make sure everyone around the world gets a chance to answer.

Comment: @pipe, first I commented that, then I thought again, and accepted. However, if you have a better answer to post, then feel free to.

Comment: What does "Ingolstadt Village" have to do with any of this? The question doesn't even mention it.

Comment: @Weirdo It's the only stop with the word "Ingolstadt" in it. I suspect the answerer assumed it to be the stop in a village named Ingolstadt, and thus where OP wanted to reach.

Answer (score 2):

I could confirm with the bus company that the bus to airport runs on May 1.

From Stadtbus Ingolstadt GmbH, I got an official answer:

> Unser Fahrplan ist das ganze Jahr über gleich. Egal ob Feiertag,
>   Samstag oder Sonntag.

which means that "Our timetable is the same all year round. No matter if holiday, Saturday or Sunday.".